# Ruby on Rails association result in errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Having a problem associating my results. Let me walk you though it:

I have 2 tables. dashboards, charts.

The charts table has a dashboard_id field as a dashboard has many charts.

So what I want in the dashboard controller is to grab the dashboard and all associated charts.  Here is what I have so far:

**Models**

```
class Dashboards < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :charts
     ....
end

class Charts < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :dashboard
     ....
end
```

**Contoller**

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
     def show 
         #an ID is passed but for testing...
         @dashboard = Dashboards.includes(:charts)
     end
end
```

**View**

/dashboards/show.html.erb

```
<%=@dashboard.inspect%>
```

**Result**

```
uninitialized constant Dashboards::Chart
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It looks pretty clean to me and I have spent a few hours researching this. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, model class names should use the singular (e.g. `Dashboard`, `Chart`, etc).  Also change the `Chart` dashboard association to:

```
class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dashboard
  ....
end
```

Now in your controller (which generally uses the plural as you have it), this should work:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  def show 
    #an ID is passed but for testing...
    @dashboard = Dashboard.includes(:charts)
  end
end
```

Comment: and remember to rename your models to chart.rb and dashboard.rb

Comment: @ProGNOMmers: good point, although I have no idea what they are currently named...

Comment: I guess they are named charts.rb and dashboards.rb because if not usually you get an error like 'expect Dashboard to define Dashboard', and he is reporting another error :-)

Comment: Thanks guys that did it. My naming was off. Cheers.